# Command Prompt Colors

Tags: c++, colors, cmd

So I was messing around with the colors in command prompt. However when I run a Console Program in MS Visual C++ the colors stay the default. Is there a way to change this so when ever the command prompt is used it will use my custom settings? Do I have to change the settings through Visual C++?

I'm running Windows 7 and MS Visual C++ 2010 Express.

I hope I am allowed to ask this question here. 
Thank you for any help.

Comment: I think the actual values are all registry keys. You *can* use the [Windows API Console Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx) for a per-run basis, though, but I think changing the registry is the only way for a more permanent effect.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

If you run the program change the color settings in the `Properties` on the console itself, then it should retain it for that program specifically, or you can change the defaults for the console window which should be persistent throughout.

Answer (score 3):

If these custom colours are specific to your application, you can build it into your code instead, using commands like [SetConsoleTextAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

There's a complete list of console functions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx

There is also an [example of using colours with the console window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686974%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This works for an application run from Visual Studio, and also from the command line.  You don't have to use `WriteFile` etc.  Once the colours are set, you can use `printf` or `cout` as normal.

Comment: paddy, thank you for your answer. It was very informative and I'll be swinging back to this to learn more about it. However, Roberto Wilko hit the nail on the head with this one. Sorry if my question wasn't worded properly, but he gave me exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: No problem.  Even though I missed the point, I'm sure you'll find this stuff useful one day.  I use it to get a cheap "debug window" for in-house windowed applications - I can send all my log messages out to a console window and colour-code them.  Very handy =)