# Get output of c++ program in fullscreen.It is a console output window targeted code

Tags: c++, windows, windows-7, console-application, windows-console

I use Windows 7 Ultimate.I set the CMD on pc to almost fullscreen(changed the properties from cmd title bar).Though taskbar is visible , it is the maximum fullscreen possible on Windows 7,I suppose.

I wrote code for a small command line user interface game.I've made a mistake by assuming the output screen to be maximized on every user's PC.

So,when I run it on another windows 7 machine,I'm getting weird output as the cmd screen is not maximized on their PC.

How can I ensure that I get the cmd screen set to fullscreen(almost fullscreen) on every PC it runs?

Can I call some functions in my code?
Or any other way?
I like to share it(the .exe file of my code) on the internet.So, how I can I fix this.

Comment: When you change the CMD settings it applies for your computer only, and only with programs of that program name or title, etc. I've never seen a program that changes its own console settings in that way. If you want this kind of fullscreen game, maybe a console app is not really the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is run the program and change the settings in that specific command window, not the default settings for your command window. You could do this with code as well, although I don't know how, but this is much easier. Then whenever that program is ran it should override the users default command settings and adhere to your program's.

Here's a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944126/command-prompt-colors/11944145#11944145) of mine to another question about command colors. Same solution should work here.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: good to know. Changing it on the console should be cross platform, probably language neutral too, for non-win apps.